# Pointers, dynamic arrays, and memory leak

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-leaks, dynamic-arrays

I'm trying to create a program which allows for a dynamically allocated array to store some integers, increase the maximum size if need be, and then display both the unsorted and sorted array in that order.

Link to my full code is at the bottom.

The first issue I have is the dynamically allocated array going haywire after the size needs to be increase the first time. The relevant code is below.

```
    while (counter <= arraySize)
    {
        cout <<"Please enter an integer number. Use 999999 (six 9's) to stop\n";
        if (counter == arraySize)           //If the counter is equal to the size of the array
        {                                   //the array must be resized
            arraySize +=2;
            int *temp = new int[arraySize];
            for (counter = 0; counter < arraySize; counter++)
            {
                temp[counter] = arrayPtr[counter];
            }
            delete [] arrayPtr;
            arrayPtr = temp;
            counter ++;                     //the counter has to be reset to it's original position
        }                                   //which should be +1 of the end of the old array
        cin >> arrayPtr[counter];
        if (arrayPtr[counter] == sentinel)
        {
            cout << "Sentinel Value given, data entry ending.\n";
            break;
        }
        counter ++;
    }
```

This produces the unintended operation where instead of waiting for the sentinel value, it just begins to list the integers in memory past that point (because no bounds checking).

The next issue is that my sorting function refuses to run. I tried testing this on 5 values and the program just crashes upon reaching that particular part of code.

The function is called using

```
sorting (arrayPtr);
```

but the function itself looks like this:

```
void sorting (int *arr)
{
    int count = 0, countTwo = 0, tempVal;

    for (count = 0; arr[count] != 999999; count++)          //I figured arr[count] != 999999 is easier and looks better
    {                                                       //A bunch of if statements
        for (countTwo = 0; arr[countTwo] != 99999; countTwo++)
        {
            if (arr[countTwo] > arr[countTwo+1])
            {
                tempVal = arr[countTwo];
                arr[countTwo] = arr[countTwo+1];
                arr[countTwo+1] = tempVal;
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Any help on this issue is appreciated.

Link to my source code:

http://www.mediafire.com/file/w08su2hap57fkwo/Lab1_2336.cpp

Due to community feedback, this link will remain active **as long as possible.**

The link below is to my corrected source code. It is annotated in order to better highlight the mistakes I made and the answers to fixing them.

http://www.mediafire.com/file/1z7hd4w8smnwn29/Lab1_2336_corrected.cpp

Comment: Unless this is for educational reasons, you should never use raw `new` and `delete`. `std::vector` is a much better alternative for dynamic arrays.

Comment: It is for educational reasons.

Comment: *This will be active until my questions get answered.* -- And then this question on SO becomes worthless since that link would no longer exist.

Comment: I did try to include the relevant code to answering my question which IS the point of asking. The code is there to provide context IF I did not provide enough. And no one is stopping you from downloading the code and providing a helpful answer with the extra (if any) context needed to do so. But I doubt anyone came to this question to watch others argue about this. Please, if your comment is not relevant to the question at hand, withhold it.

Comment: Given `arraySize +=2;`, `for (counter = 0; counter < arraySize; counter++)`, and `temp[counter] = arrayPtr[counter];` at what point to you read outside the storage pointed at by `arrayPtr`? Best I'll do since you seem uninterested in helping Stack overflow meet it's objective of leaving behind a repository of solutions for future programmers.

Comment: I have rescinded my initial intention to remove the link, as my intention was not to hamper the objective of Stack Overflow. I appreciate all of the help you have thus far given me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  first problem I can spot in your code is in the for loop where counter goes from 0 to arraySize-1,  the last two iteration of the loop will access arrrayPtr out of bounds.

Next, at the end of the `if (counter == arraySize)` there is a `counter++;`  This is not required since at this moment `counter` is already indexing the array out of bound.

Finally in your sorting function the inner loop looks for the wrong value (99999 instead of 999999), so it never stop and goes out of bounds.  To prevent this kind of error, you should define your `sentinel` as a const in an unnamed namespace and use it through the code instead of typing 999999 (which is error prone...).

Comment: I appreciate it. I also noticed that the code I uploaded had `&arrayptr` passed as a function parameter for my `sorting(int *)` function causing a compiler error. It now works perfectly.